# Modal menu links dont work when click outside modal menu to close function is active

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

I'm trying to have a modal menu that closes itself when you click outside of it but when I add a `window.onclick` function with an `event.target != nav` ( nav is the menu) the child elements inside the nav (menu options) are not affected by function and the menu closes.

```
            <nav>
                <img src="/Images/ham.png" alt="toggle menu" class="menu" id="menu"> 
                </a>

                <div>
                    <ul class="show-desktop hide-mobile" id="nav">
                        <li id="exit" class="exit-btn hide-desktop">
                            <img src="/Images/exit.svg" alt="exit menu">
                        </li>
                            <li><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="work.html">work</a></li>
                            <li><a href="about.html">about</a></li>
                            <li><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
```

I've tried adding a div with an id to the list of elements as well as an individual id to each of the option elements (index, work, about, contact) and adding successive `window.onclick` functions to match each element but it only works with 1 element not all 4.

```
 <script>

    var menu = document.getElementById('menu');
    var nav = document.getElementById('nav');
    var exit = document.getElementById('exit');

    menu.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        nav.classList.toggle('hide-mobile');
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    exit.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        nav.classList.add('hide-mobile');
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target != nav){
        nav.classList.add('hide-mobile');
        event.preventDefault();
    }}

</script>
```

```
nav ul {
    position: fixed;
    width: 60%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: left;
    background: rgb(36,41,44);
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 7;
    padding-top: 3em;
    right: 0px;
    transition: ease-out .5s;
}

nav ul li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1em 2em;
    background-color: rgb(49, 55, 59);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(65, 73, 78);
}
```

What I'm trying to get is the child elements of the ul class (id=nav) to work as links instead of closing the menu.

Comment: Hey @TDC, could you please also share your CSS, that would make it easier to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible approach and the one I've usually used, is to instead have an overlay div with 
 width and height of 100% *beneath* the modal and add the onclick handler to that overlay instead of the window object. That overlay should only be visible when the modal itself is visible, and otherwise invisible, with pointer-events:none.